# Change svg height

Tags: html, css, svg

I have a svg in my page which forces its container's height. It moves other elements... Is it possible to change svg's height? Now svg element is a square and a rectangle will be better because height is too big.

```
<svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"
viewBox="0 0 60 60" enable-background="new 0 0 30 30" xml:space="preserve" width="50%" height="11%">
    <path fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M19.7,7.6C15.3,4,9.1,4.1,5.3,7.7c-3.2,3-4,8-2.1,12
    c2.1,4.4,7.1,6.6,11.3,5.7c2.6-0.5,4.3-2.1,5.1-2.9"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="1.1572" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="19.3" y1="7.3" x2="10.8" y2="15.5"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="white" stroke-width="1.3426" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="10.9" y1="14.8" x2="19.7" y2="23.2"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.1322" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="14.7" y1="15.4" x2="23.5" y2="7.1"/>
    <line fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="0.9577" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="14.9" y1="14.9" x2="22.7" y2="22.6"/>
    <path fill="none" stroke="none" stroke-width="1.0915" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M22.9,7.2c0.3,0.1,0.6,0.4,1,0.7
    c1.8,1.4,3.9,4.2,3.4,7.9c-0.4,3-2.4,5.6-5.2,6.7"/>

    <text x="20" y="18" fill="White" class="textsvg" font-size="10">MENU</text>
</svg>
```

[Jsfiddle][1]

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look on this updated jsFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/qqzox761/1/

I removed `width` and `height` from your svg and changed viewBox a little bit.

Now with this code of svg you can set size in css.

Comment: Ok thanks! Setting `width` and `height` in svg wasn't the best way. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change the viewbox attribute, here:

```
<svg ... viewBox="0 0 60 60" ...
```

It means it is a square SVG that starts at 0, 0 and have a size of 60 on each side. Changing this will only affect the aspect ratio of SVG view, you can assign its width more accurately in pixels or percent using CSS.

Comment: Thanks, I've never used svg tag. Thank you for the explanation

Answer (score 0):

As noted by mwl, you need to delete the width and height from `<svg>`. The program you used to create the graphic adds data to `viewbox` automatically so while mwl modified it, it looks like you had extra white space when you saved the file. I also recreated your fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/samurai_jane/p7yck4zv/) but without the white space. The important thing to remember about SVG is that it's all about scaling which means, in part, that preserving the aspect ratio is more important than pixel dimensions. This is a great [article](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/) by Amelia Bellany-Royds on CSS-Tricks if you want more information.